# Problems With Escaping Black Slash In Double Quotes In A String

Tags: c#, google-cloud-firestore, expo

Not sure whats going on really.

On output, my string shows as it should with each value wrapped in double quotes with a comma.

But when I go to pass my string to query my Firestore Database it shows the backslashes.

[image]

I have tested to make sure the query actually works by manually adding the values and everything works fine.

I'm not sure if it just doesn't like how I am passing the values, really doing my head in!

```
var join = string.Join(", ", expo.SelectedItems.OfType<string>().Select(x => "'" + x.ToString() + "'").ToArray());

        String withDoubleQuotes = join.Replace("'", "\"");
        var tokens = withDoubleQuotes;
```

**EDIT**

I have a Listbox that shows a list of tokens.
I want to update each document in my Firestore for each selected item in my Listbox.

So using this query from FireBase it will update each document that contains the values "USA" or "Japan" in the Field Country.

```
Query query = citiesRef.WhereIn("Country", new[] { "USA", "Japan" });
```

I want to be able to do the same but get the values based on which are selected.

**My Query**

```
var join = string.Join(", ", listBox.SelectedItems.OfType<string>().Select(x => "'" + x.ToString() + "'").ToArray());

            String withDoubleQuotes = join.Replace("'", "\"");

            var tokens = withDoubleQuotes;

Query query = database.Collection("users").WhereIn("tokens", new[] { tokens } );
```

It doesn't work when I do it this way.

Comment: You're looking in the debugger - that's escaping the double quotes for you. The backslashes aren't actually present in the string. Print the string to the console and you'll see that. (It's not really clear to what you're expecting, or how Firestore is involved here. A [mcve] would really help.)

Comment: Please see edit

Comment: The question is clear. I thought it wasn't removing the backslashes. I did print the string as I said and it was showing fine. It was confusing me because it was showing in the debugger with the backslashes.

Comment: what do you want to achieve with the new[]{tokens} ? do you want to have an array of objects with the string properties or just one object with one string?

Comment: "The question is clear." That's not really for the *author* of a question to say - it's certainly not clear to *me* as a reader (and as the author of the C# Firestore library - it's not like I'm unaware of the Firestore query aspect). But it now looks like the problem is that you're trying to use `WhereIn` with a single value, but you actually *want* to check whether it's in any of multiple values. Maybe. Hard to say really, without sample data. Again - the question is unclear.

Comment: The debugger shows it escaped so that you can copy and paste it into a string literal.

Comment: I was asking why I was still seeing backslashes after escaping, seeing them in the debugger threw me off. All is working now anyway.

Comment: "I was asking why I was still seeing backslashes after escaping" - in that case everything about Firestore is irrelevant, and a [mcve] would have been a console app of about 3 lines. The more irrelevant code you include, the harder it is to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be sanitizing your text and removing random accent characters such as quotes where it's not needed. Using a debugger escapes characters and can lead to misrepresented data, I find console logging to be more accurate in the order of events for this purpose.

Firestore also displays quotes around string text values in the console but these are not attached to the value itself, simply a cosmetic change to denote that it is a string and not another data type, such as an object map or array.